# Using Excel Linest function without ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Is it possible to use the Linest Function when my data is not in a continuous range? I've got my known Y's in J1, J4, J7 etc. and my known X's in A1, A4, A7...

`linest(J1, J4, J7, A1, A4, A7)` doesn't work because it counts every entry as a separate input.
`linest(J1:J7, A1:A7)` doesn't work because the cells in between are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, but...

You can use `SLOPE(J1:J7, A1:A7)` and `INTERCEPT(J1:J7, A1:A7)`

these ignore empty cells, while LINEST doesn't