# Excel LINEST returns #REF error when using non-rectangular array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, regression

I'm trying to use the LINEST() function on a named range. The function seems to work fine when the named ranges are typical rectangular arrays. However, if the named arrays are irregularly shaped, the function returns a #REF error (usually occurs when the arrays are not of the same length), even though the named ranges have the same number of cells. [See screenshot below for example]

[image: Excel screenshot]

Any idea how to work around this?

**Things I have tried:**

- I have tried using the SLOPE() or INTERCEPT() functions to accomplish the same result (as SLOPE and INTERCEPT are [known to ignore empty cells](https://superuser.com/questions/250156/using-excel-linest-function-without-ranges), while the LINEST function doesn't). But, that returns a #VALUE error.
- I have also tried manually constructing an array to feed into the function. For example, =LINEST({Z9:AC9,AA10},{Z6:AC6,AA7},true, true). Unfortunately, that doesn't work either, as excel will only recognize actual numbers inside a manually constructed array (no ranges, letters, etc allowed).
- I have tried working around the problem with various INDIRECTS, but these inevitably run up against the same problem from the second bullet point.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is possible, though can I first ask whether the ranges you have defined could not be reconstrued so that they comprise the smallest rectangular area which contains your data points, after which we could perform some operation to exclude any non-numerical entries from those ranges? As you have yourself seen, not all functions work so well on ranges which comprise a union of one or more sub-ranges. A solution can be achieved with such ranges, though it's a little more complex so I thought I'd first ask.

Comment: I think you will need to reconstruct your data into single column (or row) arrays; and then apply the LINEST function to that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld True, that would be by far the most practical solution, though it's not impossible with such ranges as the OP currently has.

Comment: @XORLX Unfortunately, it's not possible to reconstruct the ranges to comprise a rectangular area. Totally agreed with you and Ron that that would be by far the easiest way to approach this problem. Unfortunately, the circumstances just don't allow it. Very curious to hear the solution you have in mind, even if it is rather complex!